# Dates in .net vs in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, date, asp.net-web-api

I have a ASP.NET WEB.API 4 and a Controller returning the following json:

```
{   date: "2013-03-14T00:00:00"   }
```

I parse it on the client (JavaScript):

```
date = new Date(json.date); // json.date being "2013-03-14T00:00:00"
```

Later I do a POST and in the body the date has changed format to

```
{   date: "2013-03-13T23:00:00.000Z"   }
```

My guess was that some time zone stuff has been added by JavaScript or the browser?

Because of DB storing dates as int (yyyymmdd) I do the following convertion:

```
public static int ToInt(DateTime date)
{
    return date.Year * 10000 + date.Month * 100 + date.Day;
}
```

The resulting int is then one day off :(

However if I do

```
date.ToLocalTime()
```

before calling the ToInt method, it looks fine.

Have I understood this correctly and is ToLocalTime() a sufficient solution or do I need to spend a day reading up on UTC dates in .NET and JavaScript?

Thanks!

Comment: welcome to the hell called "JS Date"  try using a library like datejs or momentjs :/

Comment: You're storing dates as `int (yyyymmdd)`??? What database do you use?

Comment: @Bergi sql 2000. The problem is the ppl who wrote the sw back in the 90's :)

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you will get better result if your controller will return date in ZULU format. So before sending use: ToUniversalTime (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.touniversaltime.aspx) Than the result also will be in ZULU format, so you don't have to convert it to LocalTime

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> date = new Date(json.date); // json.date being "2013-03-14T00:00:00"
> ```

And what timezone is that `json.date` in? If there's no information about this, the [JS `Date` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) will assume it is the client's local timezone (and that is quite random). If you want it to be UTC, just add `"Z"` after your ISO-datestring:

```
date = new Date(json.date+"Z");
```

Also always use the `[gs]etUTC(FullYear|Month|Date|…)` methods then.